# Assets audio player doesn't work any more

Tags: flutter, dart, try-catch, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i use flutter and i used assets_audio_player library to run sounds in my app, it was working fine until last day, when i run the code it gives me PlatformException(OPEN,nul,null,null).

I tried to change the version and also tried to restart the app but nothing worked.

I used AudioWidget.assets() to run the sound, it was working fine but when version 3.0.6 was released it didn't work and gives a rethrow error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJpO5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0OD3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6tO3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be an Incompatibility or even some error that could happen with build files being not updated or synchronised.

Just to have a clear conscience, please, on your project terminal, run the very old classic:

```
flutter clean
```

Then, run

```
flutter pub get
```

Stop your running project and rebuild your application

In fact, if it doesn't solve your problem, i would suggest you to downgrade the assets_audio_player to the previous version to when it was working.

Update me if none of this solve your problem.

Comment: hello macros, thanks, your answers worked .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing my asset String:

'sounds/x.ogg'  to ->  'assets/sounds/x.ogg'

make sure your audio path is exactly like what you wrote in pupspec.yaml